# How change text of variable after click row in AnyChart?

Tags: angular, anychart

I use anyChart for build gantt graph. I am trying to change the title text when clicking on a row element. But didn't work. I add default variable `title` with value `123`. And then, when clicking on a row element, the text should be changed to `567567`. Maybe angular does not allow assigning a value to a variable inside a listener. Maybe I don't know something.

Below is my example.
Maybe someone knows how to do it

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8bb7cu) my example

Comment: You are using anyChart by directly importing the javascript file. The listener function in the anyChart is doing things out of the scope of angular. That's why it has no access to the component variables.

Comment: I believe anyChart has an angular package for it. You should use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to AnyChart. The problem was that your title in HTML has a unique id, but in the application code you trying to get the title DOM element using its class name (which is not assigned). That's why the `high` variable was undefined. To solve the issue you should get the title element by id, so the listener will look like this:

```
    this.chart.listen('rowSelect', function (event) {
      var high = document.getElementById("tit");
          high.innerHTML = '123123123';
    });
```